# Building a new PC, Installing XP, blue screen of death

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bsod

I got a gigabyte barebones kit and am installing windows-XP(SP1) and the initial setup works, then it restarts and goes into the second phase of the setup. Then when installing components (I think that's what it says) it gets half way done and comes up with a blue screen saying IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.

BUT! I had gotten past that by installing windows-XP media center addition

Now I am trying to install the drivers for my Asus ATI Radeon 5770 graphics card and I get another blue screen of death that doesnt give much info something about address x0000005.

**Would you think there is something wrong with something in my system or do you think if I got windows 7 that would take care of things? Sorry for probably not giving enough info.**

Here is what I have

MotherBoard - Gigabyte S-series GA-H55M-S2(v)
PSU - Ultra 500 watt atx 
HDD - Sata serial ATA Seagate Baracudda 7200
CPU - Intel i3
Memory - 4gig crucial
Graphics Card - Asus ATI Radeon 5770 1Gig DDR5

Comment: I don't know whether Windows 7 will install without a hitch, but I guarantee it'll be more stable, secure, and modern than XP. I'd be surprised if you could get XP fully up-to-date before it becomes infected.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but is possible that the error is caused by faulty hardware or some bad driver. I have a laptop that will only work without BSDs if I install one version of the driver for my wireless internet card, but not with this other version I had. So it is worth a try to test with different (newer?) drivers. Or perhaps, as you say, Win 7 does things differently so that things would work with Win 7—I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not windows will blue screen over device drivers. Go to the manufacturer's site and make sure you have the latest version of the video card driver.

You could go the Windows 7 route since it will locate and install a working driver for most hardware. From there you can get the latest driver from the manufacturer's web site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to boot into Safe Mode to install the updated drivers if you can't boot into Windows normally.

Tap F8 repeatedly during the boot process to bring up a boot menu, and choose Safe Mode.